# Ways to buy marbles (Arrangement)

Tags: combinatorics

A boy wishes to buy exactly six marbles. There are four different colours of marbles available. In how many ways can he buy the six marbles?

Comment: I've no idea. Can give some hints?

Comment: Have you studied combinations with repetition?

Comment: The Wikipedia article on Stars and Bars (combinatorics) is quite good. There are also many Stars and Bars problems on MSE.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig. I just realised there's no example for combinations with repetition in my textbook.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it after viewing the article.

$C(4,6)=\frac{(4+6-1)!}{6!(4-1)!}$=84